# Add a parent to a group of nodes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following structure:

```
  <h3>I.</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    <ol>    
        <li>1.</li>
        <li>2.</li>
        <li>3.</li>
    </ol>
    <p>Some text</p>

    <h3>II.</h3>
            <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>

    <p>Some text</p>
    <ol>    
        <li>1.</li>
        <li>2.</li>
        <li>3.</li>
    </ol>
    <h3>III</h3> 
    etc
```

I would like to add a div element in such way:

```
  <h3>I.</h3>
   <div>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    <ol>    
        <li>1.</li>
        <li>2.</li>
        <li>3.</li>
    </ol>
    <p>Some text</p>
   </div>
    <h3>II.</h3>
   <div>
            <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>

    <p>Some text</p>
    <ol>    
        <li>1.</li>
        <li>2.</li>
        <li>3.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
    <h3>III</h3> 
    etc
```

I managed to figure out how to get the elements up to the next `h3`, but then I'm stuck.

```
var elements = $("h3").nextUntil("h3");
            elements.wrapAll("<div>");
```

Comment: So, do you want to enclose every `ul` and its successive `ol` with `div`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there are multiple `h3` elements you need to loop over them and use `nextUntil()` within the loop:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div />');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvyheyr/)

Comment: What if we need to add attributes to the `div` such as `class`?

Comment: Then you can use the standard jQuery method of creating elements: http://jsfiddle.net/srvyheyr/1/

Comment: thanks! This works but what if I wanted to only apply this for h3's that are after a specific h2 element (all previous ones ignored)?

Comment: Then you would need to use the direct sibling selector: `$('h2 ~ h3')`: http://jsfiddle.net/srvyheyr/3/

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('</div>');
});
```

Please try with this.